# How can i realize a semi-private research diary blog

Tags: feed, private

We are a group of researchers who would like to each use a blog as our research diary. Regularly we would write down in a post what we have been doing, intermediate results, to do's, challenges ahead, ...

The thing is that many research ideas are so preliminary that you would not like to share them with the wide world for different reasons (not wanting to make a fool of yourself if the idea appears to have some flaws, not wanting to let other people run away with your ideas). However, within our research group, there is enough trust that we can share these preliminary ideas, which could be beneficial.

At the same time, it would be nice if we could share more mature research writings with the research community.

So, we want a setup where we can mark posts as private which are only accessible to the members of the blog (people in our research group). While this appears not to be so difficult according to google, the following two requirements are less trivial:

- find an efficient way to discover new posts without having to visit each others blog each day (It appears that private feeds are not well supported by feed readers).
- combine private posts with regular posts that are accessible to the outside world.

any hints on how to set this up would be great. I have been googling for hours for private feeds and readers that can read those, but I did not find any solution that really seemed user friendly.

Comment: Why don't simply create a single blog with multiple users? Posts to be private can be published as private, post to be public as... public. Then you can disable new user registration so only existing users can read private posts. Being an unique blog all of you need only to visit one single blog. You'll discover so fast any new posts, public or private. Only additional effort can be something to notify if a private post has been updated, after first publish. Maybe you can code a dashboard widget for the scope.

Comment: Interesting approach. The only drawback is that if people already have their personal (research) blog, this enforces them to maintain two blogs or to drop their own blog. In an ideal world it would be possible to make posts private, set up a feed that contained only public posts and a private feed that contained all posts and simply use the private feed in our current feed readers.

However, this seems to be impossible which makes your suggestion a good alternative. Thanks!

Comment: If the existing blogs are on WordPress you can create a WP multisite install and move all the blogs there. After that you can use one of the blog in the network as "shared" blog. This should make things easier.